# Trying to create a program that trim videos with python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that can trim videos with ability to use browse for choosing input and output locations and also can edit/trim the video with a slider to make it easy but I have a problem and I searched alot for a solution.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
import numpy as np
import cv2

class VideoTrimmer:
    def __init__(self, master):
        
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Video Trimmer")
        
        self.video_path_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Video path:")
        self.video_path_label.pack()
        self.video_path_entry = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.video_path_entry.pack()
        self.browse_video_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Browse", command=self.browse_video)
        self.browse_video_button.pack()
        
        self.start_time_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Start time (seconds):")
        self.start_time_label.pack()
        self.start_time_entry = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.start_time_entry.pack()
        
        self.end_time_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="End time (seconds):")
        self.end_time_label.pack()
        self.end_time_entry = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.end_time_entry.pack()
        
        self.output_path_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Output path:")
        self.output_path_label.pack()
        self.output_path_entry = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.output_path_entry.pack()
        self.browse_output_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Browse", command=self.browse_output)
        self.browse_output_button.pack()
        
        self.video_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, width=640, height=480)
        self.video_frame.pack()
        self.slider_frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.slider_frame.pack()
        
        self.trim_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Trim Video", command=self.trim_video)
        self.trim_button.pack()
        
        
        self.cap = None
        self.photo = None
        self.video_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.video_frame, width=640, height=480)
        self.video_canvas.pack()
        
        
        self.slider = tk.Scale(self.slider_frame, from_=0, to=0, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=640, command=self.slider_changed)
        self.slider.pack()
        
    def browse_video(self):
        
        filetypes = [("MP4 files", "*.mp4"), ("AVI files", "*.avi"), ("All files", "*.*")]
        filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=filetypes)
        
        
        self.video_path_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.video_path_entry.insert(0, filepath)
        
        
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filepath)
        self.slider.configure(to=int(self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))-1)
        self.slider.set(0)
        self.update_video_player()
        
    def browse_output(self):
        
        filetypes = [("MP4 files", "*.mp4"), ("All files", "*.*")]
        filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=filetypes, defaultextension=".mp4")
        
        
        self.output_path_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.output_path_entry.insert(0, filepath)
        
    def trim_video(self):
    
        start_time = float(self.start_time_entry.get())
        end_time = float(self.end_time_entry.get())

    
        fps = int(self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        start_frame = int(start_time * fps)
        end_frame = int(end_time * fps)

    
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, start_frame)

    
        output_path = self.output_path_entry.get()
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')

    
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_path, fourcc, fps, (640, 480))

    
        for frame_num in range(start_frame, end_frame):
         ret, frame = self.cap.read()
         if not ret:
            break
         writer.write(frame)

    
        self.cap.release()
        writer.release()

    
        messagebox.showinfo("Trimming Complete", "Video trimming complete.")
    
        def update_video_player(self):
       
         ret, frame = self.cap.read()
         if not ret:
            return
        
       
         frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
         frame = np.rot90(frame)
         frame = np.flipud(frame)
         frame = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
        
       
         if self.photo is None:
            self.photo = self.video_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=frame, anchor=tk.NW)
         else:
            self.video_canvas.itemconfig(self.photo, image=frame)
        
       
         self.master.after(30, self.update_video_player)
        
        def slider_changed(self, value):
       
         frame_num = int(value)
         self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_num)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    VideoTrimmer(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'VideoTrimmer' is not defined
  File "D:\Programs\Visual Studio\Video-trimmer.py", line 141, in VideoTrimmer
    VideoTrimmer(root)
  File "D:\Programs\Visual Studio\Video-trimmer.py", line 7, in <module>
    class VideoTrimmer:
NameError: name 'VideoTrimmer' is not defined
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\Programs\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\alber\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\alber\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\alber\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\alber\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "c:\Users\alber\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\alber\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Programs\Visual Studio\Video-trimmer.py", line 7, in <module>
    class VideoTrimmer:
  File "D:\Programs\Visual Studio\Video-trimmer.py", line 141, in VideoTrimmer
    VideoTrimmer(root)
NameError: name 'VideoTrimmer' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `main` clause is not in the scope of the module, but in the scope of the class definition. You might try un-indenting the `if __name__ == "__main__":` to the left margin (leave an indent for the code after that line).